# My magento automatically invoices my customers?

Tags: invoice

When a customer places an order on my website. My Magento is automatically invoicing my customers.

We are a wholesale company and have various customer options. Some customers we will not invoice until the end of the month.

I am confused as to why this is automatically doing it.

We also have the EasyPDF plugin installed. I am not sure if this is causing the issues.